# how to work blob webkitslice method in safari browser

Tags: jquery, file-upload, safari, blob

i have some problems

i have create blob and wekitslice method in jquery. this are perfectly work on Mozilla, opera, and chrome browser but it is not supported in safari browser

following my jquery code:

```
var blob = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576; // 1MB chunk sizes.
    var SIZE = blob.size;
    BYTES_PER_CHUNK=Math.round(SIZE/100);
var start = 0;
    var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    window.uploadcounter=0;
    window.uploadfilearray = [];

    while( start < SIZE ) 
    {
        if(typeof blob.slice === 'function') 
        {
            var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);// if mozill,opera and chrome this condition call 
        }else if(typeof blob.webkitSlice === 'function')//this not perform condition use safari 
        {
            var chunk = blob.webkitSlice(start, end);
        }
        window.uploadfilearray[window.uploadcounter]=chunk;
        window.uploadcounter=window.uploadcounter+1;
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    }
```

this problem any solution ???